# Change opt+backspace binding to ctrl+backspace

Tags: keybindings

I have made a ~/Library/Keybindings/ and saved something like this as DefaultKeyBinding.dict. What I would like to do is options + backward_delete with control + backward_delete but I don't know the mapping for this. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `~\U0008` with `^\U0008`

`~` = Option

`^` = Control

`\U0008` = Backspace

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d#file-defaultkeybinding-dict)